# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, logging, attributeerror, telethon

I wrote imports as usual, but it is wrong. I searched and did not find a mistake like mine, please help. The file name is `main.py` .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/main.py", line 2, in <module>
from telethon import TelegramClient, Button, events, version
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .client.telegramclient import TelegramClient
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from .telegrambaseclient import TelegramBaseClient
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 3, in <module>
import asyncio
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .base_events import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
import concurrent.futures
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 7, in <module>
import logging
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from string import Template
File "/app/string.py", line 7, in <module>
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/events/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .raw import Raw
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/events/raw.py", line 1, in <module>
from .common import EventBuilder
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/events/common.py", line 5, in <module>
from .. import utils
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/utils.py", line 22, in <module>
from .extensions import markdown, html
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/extensions/markdown.py", line 9, in <module>
from ..helpers import add_surrogate, del_surrogate, within_surrogate, strip_text
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/helpers.py", line 20, in <module>
_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, my python file was called token.py. Once I renamed it into something else the problem went away.

Comment: You are the winner of the internet for today. I had the same issue. Thanks